# format date in java as "Day Month number, year"

Tags: java, date

The following code prints the date "Thu, 10 Oct 2013"

```
Date date = new Date(timeInMilliSec);
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy");
String dateText = df2.format(date);
return dateText;
```

How do I get "Thu Oct 21, 2013"?

Comment: Have you tried moving the `,` and the patterns? How do you expect it to go from 10 to 21? Many things are unclear in your question.

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this line you define how your output looks like :

```
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy");
```

Changing the string is changing the format, at your example you need this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy");
```

If you look to documentation, you can see what each character means. If character does not mean anything, it is parsed to the output as it is, otherwise it is changed to things like "day in month in -dd- input"

[Documentation of SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Actually, it is more "EEE MMM dd, yyyy". But I’m still wondering how the 10th is supposed to switch to 21.

Comment: Tx, I am blind :)... well I suppose that number switching is just mistake.